# How to sum characters and digits with regex?

Tags: regex

I have a situation with a pattern that always has `length = 6`, stating with characters and finishings with numbers. I may have 2 to 5 characters, completing length to 6.

Examples:

```
ABCDE1
ABCD12
ABC123
AB1234
```

Today we use a Regex like this `([A-Z]{4}\d{2}|[A-Z]{3}\d{3}|[A-Z]{5}\d{1})` but it can grow, and make this solution turn into a monster.

There is a way where I can get how many characters I have to set how many digits I should have?

OBS: We always have characters and then digits, never mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can assert 6 chars A-Z or digits. Then start the match with 2-5 chars A-Z and match 1+ digits.

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]{6}$)[A-Z]{2,5}\d+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]{6}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 6 chars either A-Z or a digit till end of string
- `[A-Z]{2,5}` Match 2-5 chars A-Z
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U3bmTS/1)

Comment: You can replace `[A-Z0-9]` with `.` here. `^(...)[A-Z]{2,5}\d+$` already excludes non-alphanumericals.

Comment: @RuudHelderman You can do that, but if the first 6 chars are `!!!!!!` the positive lookahead will still succeed, and will fail at the match. You can fail the lookahead immediately by assering 6 chars A-Z0-9.